# Is this any way to set different category of configure product and it's child product?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configurable-product, simple-product, url-key

Is this any way to set different category of configure product and it's child product?
I want to display child product on listing page and its parent visibility is not visible,
but i what that anyone search that configure product using url-key product page will be open.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this any way to set different category of configure product and
> it's child product?

Yes you can manually edit the simple products and update its categories ..